# Value at poiComment of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

Good Morning people,
my head is going to explode cause of this error

Value {...} at poiComment of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

this is the json file:

```
    {
    "poiComment": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "poiComment": "I'm at The Pine. http://4sq.com/a1UXvc"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "poiComment": "bday dinner w. my bff &lt;3 (@ The Pine) http://4sq.com/a1UXvc"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "poiComment": "I'm at The Pine. http://4sq.com/a1UXvc"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i use this way (last time i used a jsonobject it worked):

```
JSONObject jso1 = new JSONObject(response1);
JSONArray jArray1 = jso1.getJSONArray("poiComment");
```

How is it possible??

Thanks in advance for help

This is what the parser do

```
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            // Read response until the end
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

        // Return full string
        return total.toString();
    }
```

This is what the parser produces !!!????!!!??! How is possible? :(

```
 {"poiComment":{"id":"1","poiComment":"Nadoori no more. Watching peeps plan a new restaurant, Yuba (@ Nadoori) http://4sq.com/8yVoey"}}
```

Comment: are you sure this is the entire json response. what you have posted looks fine

Comment: Are you sure the parser somehow doesn't trying to read the inner "poiComment" key?

Comment: It seems you get it like this from the input stream. Maybe the source suppresses the array if there is only one record.

Comment: Yes but in my case the are 3 items in the array